# How to connect to a remote desktop using Tight VNC server

Tags: vnc, remote-access

Can some one suggest me the best network application debugging tools. As
I am trying to connect to remote VNC server uisng windows 7. I have diabled windows firewall and antivirus but sitll not able to connect to the remote server. I have also tried Putty to connect to the remote pc but was not successfull. But when I try to access the PC using windows I can access the shared documents.

Comment: I am able to connect to the VNC server on local host the problem is that I am not able to connect to server remotly.

Comment: how 'remote' is 'remote'? intranet? need to traverse routers (nat)?

Answer (score 1):

Can you `tracert` to the remote server successfully? If not, at was point does the trace stop?  If you can, check the configuration on the server, as VNC can be configured to reject connections based on different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It might be time to check out pcap or wireshark, just to make sure that the connection is going out on the line. Perhaps running winpcap on the server (or tcpdump, if the server is UNIX) would help you isolation the problem to your host or to your server.